# PHP print SQL query in JSON format

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to get data from `MySQL` database in `json` format and then print it to a `PHP` page.

I try to use this script:

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $start = 0;
    $limit = 5;
    require_once('dbConnect.php');
    $total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id from photos"));
    $page_limit = $total/$limit;

    if($page<=$page_limit){
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

        $sql = "SELECT * from photos limit $start, $limit";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $res = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            array_push($res, array(
                "location"=>$row['location'],
                "image"=>$row['image'])
                );
        }
        echo json_encode($res);
    }else{
            echo "over";
    }
```

Database connection is OK, but it gives "over" message. Table contains 1 record, which details should be listed in `JSON` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$total` is 1.

`$limit` is 5.

`$page_limit` is 1/5. (PHP will not cast to int).

`$page` is 1.

`$page <= $page_limit` is false.

To make your code work the way you're expecting, make `$page_limit = ceil($total/$limit);`.